# Alt+TAB, mulitple rows

Tags: gnome

I like to use alt-Tab to switch between my numerous openened windows.

When I have too many windows opened, I don't see all of them at once.
I would like the alt+tab menu to display my openened app **over multiple rows** so I can see all of them at once, like it's done on window.
This can be also interpreted as line wraping for the alt+Tab menu

edit: I'm running ubuntu 20.04
[image: window]
Any plugin/feature extension suggestions ?

Comment: And your Ubuntu release/version is...? Solutions very likely will depend on the specific desktop environment.

Comment: it is ubuntu 20.04